# Can I automatically have Figures be auto-fitted according to my margins?

Tags: floats, newfloat

First question here. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way that i can automatically have a figure like the second one in the 2nd page be in the paramaters of the margins i have set. I would like to figure out if this can be done to make it easier for me to edit figures. Document isn't 100% my own coding, but it works for everyone who has used it.

The document has LuaLaTeX enabled.

```
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat} % replaces float (ask how to use it)
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subcaption} % has caption
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage[main=english,spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vspace{-0.125cm} % This corresponds to the top margin set by geometry
\begin{center}
\parskip=0pt
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\LARGE \@title \par }%
\vspace{0cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the title and author
{\large \lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}%
\par }%
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the author and date
{\large \@date }%
\end{center}\par 
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the date and content after maketitle
}
\makeatother % ask if you want to change the spacing of the 3 top sections

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % this makes tables look better

\setlength\parindent{.5cm}

% }

\title{The Endangered Status of the Texas Horned Lizard}
\author{David Patterson}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{1}. Introduction}
\end{large}
\end{center}

The Texas Horned Lizard (\textit{Phrynosoma cornutum}) is a reptilian that is native to many areas of the south and can be found in much of both general Texas and East Texas. The Texas Horned Lizard is a brown and white lizard with black eyes and is becoming an endangered species in the previously mentioned areas. The animal was listed on the endangered species list in 1977, and many efforts are being made to keep the species alive.

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{horned_lizardlarge.jpg}
    \caption*{Fig. 1: A picture of a Texas Horned Lizard~(\textit{Phrynosoma cornutum}).}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{2}. Why is the Texas Horned Lizard Endangered?}
\end{large}
\end{center}

While there is  not one sole factor for the endangered status of the species, the main contributing factors to the species endangerment is habitat loss, over collection, and pesticide use. There is also the possibility of  of fire ants also playing a role in its endangerment. 

\newpage

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{04_figure.jpg}
    \caption*{Fig. 2: A statistic showing the population of the Texas Horned Lizard, with it having a low distribution percentage in the Pineywoods area.}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{3}. The Fight for the Species}
\end{large}
\end{center}

While many people may not be aware of how serious the issue of the endangered species is, the Texas Horned Lizard Reintroduction Project has begun at the San Antonio Zoo, and they are looking to be able to bring back the species out of endangerment status, by working with private landowners to have them breed, promoting ecotourism, and getting funding to make the mission possible.

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{SA-Horned-Lizard.jpg}
    \caption*{Fig. 3: A baby lizard breed at the San Antonio Zoo, as part of the Texas Horned Lizard Reintroduction Project.}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{4}. The Effects of the Extinction of This Species}
\end{large}
\end{center}

There are effects that will be found with the extinction of the Texas Horned Lizard. Firstly, the state of Texas will lose an animal with a cultural tie to it, and it will be of much loss if it were to disappear. Secondly, the harvester ant (\textit{Pogonomyrmex rugosus}) population would explode, and there would be no consumer to keep its population in check. Lastly, they provide biodiversity to the ecosystem they are a part of, and if gone, this can bring forth a huge effect on the ecosystem.

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{41592_2022_1671_Fig1_HTML.png}
    \caption*{Fig. 4: A picture of the harvester ant~(\textit{Pogonomyrmex rugosus}).}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{5}. Conclusion}
\end{large}
\end{center}

The Texas Horned Lizard is still classified as endangered, and this is happening for many reasons. While there are many factors responsible for the endangered status that it is in right now, many things are being done to reverse the process. Human intervention plays a big role in helping the population make a comeback, and there are many groups/organizations helping the species repopulate.

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{6}. Look at how adorable they are!}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
They are so cute! Why wouldn't you want to have these around?
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{thl_adult_baby.jpg}
    \caption*{Fig. 5: Lets help these guys repopulate!}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Make your example shorter. Most of your packages are not relevant. And use a generic image like example-image. Then everyone can test your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It already has the important option: `\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth] ...` . You could drop the 0.6 ... HOWEVER, to make this work smoothly you'd need to restrict the xy-format of all input-drawings, just like newspapers or magazines do.

Comment: You can reduce the width of a `\caption` by putting it inside a minipage or `\parbox`.  If you don't know the width, use a savebox to find out.

Comment: @MS-SPO how is the xy-format change done? i don't know how to do that

Comment: @JohnKormylo i would actually like to know if it is possible to have a caption's text be indented, as it it were a piece of regular text.  putting `\caption*{Fig. 1: A picture of a Texas Horned Lizard~(\textit{Phrynosoma cornutum}).}` into `\parbox{}` or `\begin{minipage \end{minipage}` didn't work. is there a way to get what I want? My preamble has .25cm as the default indentation size btw.

Comment: You do it at the source, the image. Taking your screenshot as an example if the bar charts would fill the textwidth AND at the same height AND undistorted … the input image may not exceed, roughly, a 2:1 ratio. I.e. supply a 1:1 format, and you‘ll need too much space from the text. I.e. an input image at ratio 1:2 is a total fail. // Consider space being a rare resource and do a little research, how publishers do it.

Comment: Your first image is 0.5\textwidth wide and centered, so a minipage with the same width will have the same (0.25\textwidth) margins on both sides.  The only thing in your preamble with .25cm are a couple of \vspace commands.  Nor is \parindent specified.

Comment: you should fix the example so it's usable but `[width=\textwidth,height=.7\textheight,keepaspectrio]` possibly does what you want, hard toi tell with no usable example.

Comment: General comments on the document as it stands: replace `\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{number}. Section heading text}
\end{large}
\end{center}` with `\section{section heading text}`. Replace `\caption*` with `\caption`. Replace `\label{fig:enter-label}` with a specific label, for example `\label{fig:graph-population}`. For your final copy (I am assuming that this is a draft), remove `showframe` from the `geometry` package options.

Comment: Once those changes are done, if you have specific changes you want, ask a specific question (e.g. "how do I make section numbers have a number then a dot, then 2 cm of space before the heading", or "how do I make the caption have "Fig. 2" rather than "Figure 2"). Those questions are far more easily answered by people here.